# Passed properties not updated from re-rendering using (Material-ui + React Redux + Next.js in SSR)

Tags: redux, react-redux, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

Hi I am not sure whether it's bug or I appreciate if someone can help me.

I used Next.js v10+ with Material-UI and React Redux / Redux in SSR.
Actually I have a Redux Prop passed to the useStyles:

```
const extended = useSelector(state => state.someStore.extended);
const classes = useStyles({
    extended
});
```

and used in makeStyles:

```
toolbar: {
    height: props => props.extended ? 180 : 600
}
```

When the event that updates "extended", re-rendering occurs. However, the "extended" kept the old value 180 but not 600.

The above is fine when in development mode but it's problematic in SSR.
I tried using styled-components in SSR and it worked as expected.

Do I miss some config in Material UI + Redux + SSR?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Need more information on how do you update the `extended` value (i.e. action, reducer). It is also not clear what that has to do with server side rendering. Are there inconsistencies between server and client renders?

Comment: Yes, I updated the "extended" property by dispatching a Redux event.

Answer (score 0):

Redux/React Redux is fine. I have to use clsx to solve the problem.

(Below codes are all cases for Next.js SSR)

CASE 1 (it works!):

```
<Toolbar className={clsx(classes.toolbar, expanded && classes.expanded)} />
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    toolbar: {
        height: 180
    },
    expanded: {
        height: 600
    }
}));
```

CASE 2 (it doesn't works! (my original work):

```
const classes = useStyles({ expanded });
<Toolbar className={classes.toolbar} />
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    toolbar: {
        height: props => props.expanded ? 600 : 180
    }
}));
```

CASE 3 (It works!):
While it's fine using styled-components like this way:

```
<Toolbar expanded={expanded} />
const Toolbar = styled.div`
    height: ${props => props.expanded ? '600px' : '180px'};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to pass the `expanded` prop to the `useStyles` hook, but it doesn't expect any argument.
To make it work you could try the following:

```
const useStyles = ({ expanded }) =>
  makeStyles({
    toolbar: {
      height: expanded ? 180 : 600
    }
  });

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const expanded = useSelector(state => state.someStore.expanded);
  const classes = useStyles({ expanded })();

  return <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar} />;
}
```

You can also refer to [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-s7tjt?file=/demo.tsx)